# Mongodb on Azure VM : Mongodb not reachable

Tags: java, mongodb, macos, azure, virtual-machine

**Case 1**. I installed `mongo` on my machine (Mac OS), and `mongo` is configured with `bind-ip : 127.0.0.1`. A remote machine in LAN can connect to my mongodb using my IP.  (Wrong observation : See UPDATE section)

**Case 2**. I installed `mongo` on `Azure Ubuntu VM`, mongo configured with `bind-ip:127.0.0.1`. No remote machine from the same VNet can connect to that mongo using private vnet IP.

**MongoDB Network Setting** (both case 1 and case 2):

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

**Exception** (Case 2):

> 2018-04-03 06:35:29.948  INFO 44518 --- [72.17.1.4:27017]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread
>   while connecting to server 172.17.1.4:27017
>
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/:na]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151] Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar!/:na]     ... 3 common frames omitted

Whats is different in Azure VM that it behaves differently from a Mac OS installation?

Note: Changing the `bindIp` to the `IP (172.17.1.4)` or `0.0.0.0` works.

**UPDATE:**

Case 1: The remote access on my local machine's mongo was because of the distribution I picked which was configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, `127.0.0.1` only works inside the machine, do you ensure you could access Mogodb outside your MAC OS?

Comment: See this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/), `By default, MongoDB bind to local interface only, it will restrict the remote connections. If you don’t care about security, just comment out to accept any remote connections (NOT Recommend).`

Comment: yes @ShengbaoShui-MSFT , with Mac OS , remote machines can connect. When I install on Window or Ubuntu, remote cannot connect. It seems like a issue with Mac OS, unrelated to Mongo or Azure. Whats your opinion?

Comment: On Azure, I suggest you configure like `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,172.17.1.4`.

Comment: In fact, if you want to a service could remote access, you could not configure listen it on `127.0.0.1`, you should set it listen on VM's private IP or `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Just figured out, the remote access of mongo on MacOS was happening on my machine due to some config issue. Mac OS behaves as expected like *nix.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I think only listen on `127.0.0.1`, the service could not remote access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, `127.0.0.1` only works inside machine. You could check this [blog](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/).

> By default, MongoDB bind to local interface only, it will restrict the
>   remote connections. If you don’t care about security, just comment out
>   to accept any remote connections (NOT Recommend).

I suggest you could configure Mongodb like `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,172.17.1.4`.